# Rails, where filter on an already joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, filter, include

I have a table :periods that has a column :hours

I also have a table :simulations that belongs to :period (so it has period_id as a column)

I join the 2 table

```
@simulations=Simulation.join(:period) #Controller
```

Now in my view I have to loop through my simulations but filter based on the "hours" column, which exists on the period table.

So I tried things like

In my view I have to loop through simulations:

```
<% @simulations.where( :period => {:hour => count})each do |sim| %>
```

or

```
<% @simulations.periods.where(:hour => count )each do |sim| %>
```

Again, I want to filter my simulations based on data from the period table. And neither of these approaches work. I have also tried using includes and eager_loads neither of which works.

Am I attempting something that is not possible under rails?

Also I am using postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query, in your controller

```
@simulations = Simulation.where(periods: {hours: count}) # All simulations that belongs to periods with hours = count
```

Notice, the 's' in 'periods' and adjust the 's' in 'hours' as per your column name.

In views, directly use simulations variable:

```
<%= @simulations.each do |sim| %>
```

You are making same query twice of joining periods and simulations. Also try to avoid any query on Model in views or in controller. Instead, you should make a method in Model and use it to get the results from above query.